# Autodesk Platform services; Users API call is returning inconsistent values

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In attempting to use the Project Users API  https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/ in order to display user names and emails in our integration, we are getting user lists that do not match the number of users assigned to the project.

We have several projects in Autodesk Construction Cloud, all in the same organization. The authenticated user has access to all of them.

On one project,
`curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/users`

returns nearly the full list of available users shown on the "Members" page -- 12 out of 13, excluding only the user that was calling the method.

On another project, it returns only 1 User out of 5.

On a test project I created for this specific issue, it returns no users.

All of the users have their status marked as "Active" and can be selected to assign an RFI from within the normal web page.

The user making the request has Project Administrator role on all three projects. The same access token used for all three requests and has the following scope:

`scope=data:read%20data:write%20account:read`

In all cases, I am not getting an error, just a  list of users for the response which does not correspond to the project members list in ACC.

Comment: Hi Michael, GET project users under /bim360/ is not compatible with ACC projects.  It works only for BIM 360 project.  You can find compatibility table here: 

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/bim-360-compatibility/compatibility-table/

I know it is confusing. The incompatible endpoints should be blocked in the code. But it wasn't.  The product team is working on releasing a version of get project users that works with ACC project.  

If this is not the case, and you are using BIM 360 project and still having an issue, we will need to take a took further.

Comment: Thank you for the update! That makes sense.

So the only alternative is to scan the account information with a login with admin privileges, then store it ourselves so we can display it to the user?

Comment: Or you may want to use Data Connector API. Insight has Data Connector feature, which extract data in ACC/B360 in csv format. Using API, you have slightly granular control to access them than UI, such as by project and by services. Here is the link to an example of workaround in the tutorial:    

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/issues/retrieve-available-members-roles-companies/

(That said, we are hoping to start public beta for project user soon. If you are interest in early access, please drop off a note to me at aps.help@autodesk.com I will try to follow up)